# Setting symbology based on attribute of 1-N table?

Tags: qgis, symbology

Now, it is possible to edit geographic features and add elements in child tables using 1-N relationships. I want to construct a stacked - symbology  which allows me to represent the multiple attributes.
For example if I have a line feature "linear park" and my linear park has a linked table (1-N)   called "users", i want a stacked or multi-level symbology (with some offsets) that allows me to depict all the "users" of that section of park.

Is it possible in QGIS?

I know it was possible in ArcGIS using relates.

Answer (score 1):

my collegues gave me the answer for my particular problem. Since I was using an spatialite database, it was only required to create a view between my linked tables  using the spatialite gui and incorporating the view in QGIS.
There I was able to assign the symbology.
I think that was very smart!!

Answer (score 0):

As of now, this is not possible out of the box.
It might be able to achieve something with a python plugin (no promise).

However, it sounds like a very good idea that you could add as a [feature request](http://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index#bugs-features-and-issues.html) and support this with what you are able to provide (information, mockups, development time or funding).